# I'm new to Eclipse Android app development. I'm getting this error while in the creation of new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please guide me to get fix this problem. Being stuck here from one week.

1) Action Bar is deprecated

2) R cannot resolve to a variable

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: * Clean you project and rebuild. * Remove `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`

Comment: If you are new to Android Development and Eclipse I suggest you starting with Android Studio instead Eclipse because it will be no longer supported: [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean your project (By Project -> Clean)
2. Move appcompat library to your Workspace then add it to your project library.
3. Remove all of your imports and organize it (By pressing Ctrl + O)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Clean you project and rebuild.
- Remove `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`
- Add `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

  ```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
          // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
          // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
          int id = item.getItemId();
          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
              return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Neeraj I removed and add.                                                                          import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  Now getting this on side bar 'ACTIONBAR Activity cannot be resolved to a type '                               The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a 
 R cannot resolve to a variable

Comment: Have you added the v7 support library?

Answer (score 0):

the android components you're trying to use in your code might not be compatible with the release of android on which you are using. They might be obsolete. Use other similar components instead.

Try updating your SDK. I hope this solves the problem . Because there is no problem in your code . There must be some library mismatch problem .